# "ImportError: No module" after uploading to IBM-Cloud

Tags: python, macos, module, pycharm, ibm-cloud

So I have a path structure that looks like this:

```
~/Dropbox/Coding/Python/Chessbotslack/scripts/Flask_interface.py
~/Dropbox/Coding/Python/Chessbotslack/database/spreadsheets.py
```

The first line of the *Flask_interface.py* is:

```
from Chessbotslack.database.spreadsheets import add_game
```

If I run this from my IDE (PyCharm) it runs just fine; but if I run it from my terminal it throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Flask_interface.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Chessbotslack.database.spreadsheets import add_game
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Chessbotslack'
```

To solve this I did two things:

**1) Adding __init__.py to the directories**

This did  seem to accomplish anything

**2) Adding the directory to $PYTHONPATH**

In terminal I ran

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/Dropbox/Coding/Python
```

---

This solved the problem for running it from my terminal, but as expected it did not solve it for my IBM-Cloud. Perhaps it has something to do with the requirements.txt file?

```
2018-04-16T09:08:45.30+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR   File "scripts/Flask_interface.py", line 1, in <module>
2018-04-16T09:08:45.30+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     from Chessbotslack.database.spreadsheets import add_game
2018-04-16T09:08:45.30+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR ImportError: No module named Chessbotslack.database.spreadsheets
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to a flat folder structure (every file in the Chessbotslack folder) and changing the import command from:

```
from Chessbotslack.database.spreadsheets import add_game
```

to:

```
from spreadsheets import add_game
```

solved it. The weird thing is that the IDE (PyCharm) does not recognize this as correct; only after (incorrectly) adding the folder name "Chessbotslack." in front of it the IDE helps out.

Any idea what to do about that?